# Can I get inbox emails immediately?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

Currently, there are options to send an email for inbox messages every 3 hours, daily, weekly, or never. Could you add an option to send emails out for every inbox message to provide immediate notification?

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that would be too much for the servers... However, if you want immediate notification while not having an SE site open, you could have a look at George Edison's [StackApplet](https://stackapps.com/questions/83/stackapplet-bringing-stack-exchange-notifications-to-your-desktop-1-6-alpha-f) (Windows and Linux).

Answer (score 1):

Relatively recently, [Stack Exchange announced new E-mail settings functionality](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/298906/383809). However, even in this revision, it is still only possible to get an e-mail every 3 hours.

In general, there were [some discussions on immediate inbox e-mails](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/202252/383809), as well as some discussion on [how to do it without official support from Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/60434/383809) (usually via RSS).

A direct [instant-email notification feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/6557/383809) was [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) in 2009 with a consensus that RSS should be used in this case. Personally, I've been using RSS for this purpose for a long time, including watching the tags that I am interested in.

So, I am setting a [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) for this post on our meta.